# Compare two bools with different int value

Tags: c, boolean, comparison-operators, c-standard-library

```c
#include <stdbool.h>                                                            
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
int main ()                                                                        
{                                                                                  
    bool a, b;                                                                     
    a = 1;                                                                         
    b = 4;                                                                         
                                                                                   
    if (a == b)                                                                    
        printf ("They are equal\n");                                               
    else                                                                           
        printf ("They are different\n");                                           
}
```

This code prints `They are equal`

- How can this happen? Are the variables `a` and `b` being filled with the value `0x1` in the assignment regardless of what I assign to them? Or maybe is it the `==` that has been hacked to handle `bool`s?
- Is this behaviour portable  accross C Standard Library implementations and compilers?
- What was the correct way of logically comparing two `bool`/`int` before the introduction of `stdbool.h` ?

Comment: See [C11 6.3.1.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2): *When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is `0` if the value compares equal to `0`; otherwise, the result is `1`.* So your `b` gets assigned to `1` automatically.

Comment: The value `4` (any non-0 value) means `true`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the OP wanted to know if `b` is converted to `1`, because otherwise the two booleans would be stored in memory differently and could not be compared using `==`.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang I meant that the value stored will be `true`, because `4` is considered to be true.

Comment: @WeatherVane I understand your point, but if `bool b` was stored as `4`, it would look like this in memory `00000100`, but then it would not be the same as `bool a`, which would be stored like this `00000001`. Therefore `bool b` needs to be converted to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can this happen?

Both variables are 1, so they are equal.

> Are the variables a and b being filled with the value 0x1 in the assignment regardless of what I assign to them?

Well, not regardless. Any *non-zero* value is *converted* to 1 and assigned to `bool`. A zero value will fill them with... 0.

> Or maybe is it the == that has been hacked to handle bools?

No.

It's that `bool` is a macro that expands to `_Bool` and that `_Bool` variables have special semantics when assigning a value to it.

> Is this behaviour portable accross C Standard Library implementations and compilers?

Yes.

> What was the correct way of logically comparing two bools before the introduction of stdbool.h ?

When `bool` is not an `_Bool`, but like an `int`, you can convert the values on assignment or comparison to 0 or 1 with double logical NOT:

```
if (!!a == !!b)
```

Comment: In fact `if (!a == !b)` (a single `!`) is also valid

Answer (score 1):

[C11, 6.3.1.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2) says:

> When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
> value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

When you assign `4` to `b`, it's simply assigned to 1. So yes, this behaviour is guaranteed by the C standard.